# How to HitTest on a square

Tags: flash

How would you perform hitTest on a square object?
For some reason it allows the user to enter the square from the right hand side and the top side, however this code works when the user is trying to enter the object from the bottom and left hand side. I want it so the user cannot enter the object at all. How would I do this?

This is my code:

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
if (_root.character.hitTest(this))
{
    _root.character._y += 7;

}
if (_root.character.hitTest(this))
{
    _root.character._x -= 7;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try these

http://sierakowski.eu/list-of-tips/39-collision-detection-methods-hittest-and-hittestobject-alternatives.html

Also check with hitTestObject first